# How should I combine the rows of similar time in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm processing a MIMIC dataset. Now I want to combine the data in the rows whose time difference (delta time) is below 10min. How can I do that?

The original data:

```
charttime   hadm_id age is_male HR  RR  SPO2    Systolic_BP Diastolic_BP    MAP PEEP    PO2
0   2119-07-20 17:54:00 26270240    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 103.0   66.0    81.0    NaN NaN
1   2119-07-20 17:55:00 26270240    68.0    1.0 113.0   26.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   2119-07-20 17:57:00 26270240    NaN NaN NaN NaN 92.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   2119-07-20 18:00:00 26270240    68.0    1.0 114.0   28.0    NaN 85.0    45.0    62.0    16.0    NaN
4   2119-07-20 18:01:00 26270240    NaN NaN NaN NaN 91.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   2119-07-30 21:00:00 26270240    68.0    1.0 90.0    16.0    93.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6   2119-07-30 21:00:00 26270240    68.0    1.0 89.0    9.0 94.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7   2119-07-30 21:01:00 26270240    68.0    1.0 89.0    10.0    93.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8   2119-07-30 21:05:00 26270240    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 109.0   42.0    56.0    NaN NaN
9   2119-07-30 21:10:00 26270240    68.0    1.0 90.0    10.0    93.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

After combining the rows whose delta time is less than 10 min, the output I want:

(when there is duplicate data in same column in some rows to group, just take the first one)

```
charttime   hadm_id age is_male HR  RR  SPO2    Systolic_BP Diastolic_BP    MAP PEEP    PO2
0   2119-07-20 17:55:00 26270240    68.0    1.0 113.0   26.0    92.0    103.0   66.0    81.0    16.0    NaN2119-07-30 20:00:00  26270240    68.0    1.0 90.0    16.0    93.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   2119-07-30 21:00:00 26270240    68.0    1.0 89.0    9.0 94.0    109.0   42.0    56.0    NaN NaN
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would round the timestamp column to 10 minutes:

```py
df['charttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['charttime']).dt.floor('10T').dt.time
```

Then, I would drop the duplicates, based on the columns you want to compare (for example, `hadm_id` and `charttime`:

```py
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['charttime', 'hadm_id'], keep='first', inplace=True)
```

Comment: That does not give the output I want but is truely a way to process the data! Thanks a looooot!